# Google calendar api, актуальность данных

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Работаю с google api, а конкретно с календарем. Приходят события нескольких календарей.
Интересен такой момент, необходимо раз в минуту проверять актуальность данных.
с сервера приходит ответ с заголовком 
cache-control: "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform"
Я почитал разные источники, в чем то разобрался, а в чем то нет.
Понял, что сервер может кэшировать данные у себя и отдавать в заголовке etag.
Пользуюсь axios, он не показывает этот заголовок, возможно это связано с cors или все же сервер ничего подобного не отдает.
Поэтому здесь не понятный момент, получится ли проверить актуальность данных перед тем как их получать от сервера?

Comment: В Axios до этого заголовка можно добраться, он находится в response объекте

Comment: Этот заголовок обозначает то что сервер не хочет чтобы запрос попадал в кеш

Comment: Вам ничего не нужно проверять, в теории вы должны отправить запрос с полученным etag, сервер ответит новой порцией данных или отправит заголовок "не изменено"

Comment: Cors - совсем другая степь

Comment: Я не знаю или так правильно, но я хотел добраться до etag и отправить запрос по этому же url с этим заголовком, в надежде получить ответ. И если статус не 300, то только тогда тянуть новые данные. В реале получается, если делаю один и тот же запрос 1 раз в минуту, то приходят одни и те же данные, которые и не менялись. Вообщем это не то, что я хотел, отсюда и вопрос..

Comment: Так и надо, я на память не подскажу как до респонса добраться.

Comment: Проще всего console.log командой посмотреть

Comment: У response.headers нет заголовка etag, на одном ресурсе читал что это может быть политика cors, и вопрос решается на сервере.